# Easing in animation graph editor not working at all

Tags: animation, graph-editor, interpolation

I try pressing ctrl + e on te graph but the easing type does not change at all. Screenshot shows how it looks like and what my graph editor looks like.

[image: You can see that I applied the easing but it doesn´t do anything]

Answer (score 1):

> The Easing Type controls which end of the segment between the two keyframes that the easing effects apply to. It has no effect if the [Interpolation Mode](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/graph_editor/fcurves/properties.html#editors-graph-fcurves-settings-interpolation) is set to either *Constant*, *Linear*, or *Bézier*.
>
> Source: [Properties — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/graph_editor/fcurves/properties.html#active-keyframe)

Keyframes are in Bézier interpolation by default, so you need to change the interpolation to either of the "Easing" or "Dynamic Effects" categories in the Set Interpolation Menu (shortcut <kbd>T</kbd>):

[image]

Though be honest, most people rarely ever use these, and instead stick to the Bézier interpolation and play with different handle types (shortcut <kbd>V</kbd>, usually Auto Clamped by default).

[image]